# Need help in error in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I am getting this error while clicking on the `neo4j.bat` file in Windows. I tried other answers on stackoverflow but none of them is working. I set all variables in path  `JAVA_HOME` & `JRE_HOME`. It says database incorrectly shutdown, performing recovery. And then console goes off. I have installed `jdk 1.7` & `jre7`.

```
Sep 15, 2013 11:52:57 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Sep 15, 2013 11:52:58 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@3e890800' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:280)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:114)
at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:280)
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:160)
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@3e890800' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:258)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Could not create lock file
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
... 12 more

Sep 15, 2013 11:52:58 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you have an instance already running. Kill any Java processes and try again.